# Select data which is a superset of a defined set by using JPA 2.0 Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use the JPA 2.0 Criteria API (using Hibernate implementation), to select those cars that owns the accessories defined by a set of patterns.

Please look at my code and I think you will understand what I am trying to do.

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARS")    
public class Car implements Serializable {

   // .. Other fields
    // {{ accessories
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CARS_ACCESSORIES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CARID"))
    @Column(name = "ACCESSORY", length = 25)
    private Set<String> accessories;
```

The repository / service method for Car class for finding all cars which owns an accessory/ies with a pattern:

```
public List<Car> findByAccessoryCriteria(Set<String> accessoriesCriteria) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Car> cq = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
    Root<Car> car = cq.from(Car.class);

    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if(accessoriesCriteria != null) {
       for(String accessory : accessoriesCriteria) {
           if(accessory.contains("%") {
               // TODO: Select all Cars that contains an accessory which match
               // accessory pattern.
           } else {
               // TODO: Select all Cars that contains an accessory which is 
               // equal to accessory pattern.
           }
           // TODO: Note that if a Car NOT owns an accessory which match or is equal to a
           // the pattern, the Car shall NOT be selected.
       } 
    }
    cq.select(car).where(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[criteria.size()]));
    TypedQuery<Car> query = em.createQuery(cq);
    List <Car> cars= query.getResultList();
    return cars;
}
```

Hence, if Car A owns following accessorie(s): "Accessory XYZ", "Accessory AAA" and car B owns following "Accessory XYZ", and the criteria is Set = "Accessory%", both Car A and Car B shall be selected, but if the criteria is Set = "Accessory XYZ", "Accessory AAA" only Car A shall be selected.

Can you please help me to complete this select statement? Note, that I am forced to use the criteria API and the Hibernate framework.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being forced to use Hibernate is not relevant here as this is a JPA criteria query.  Anyway...

```
if (accessoriesCriteria != null) {
   // we have accessory restrictions...

   // now apply each incoming restriction
   for (String accessoryCriteria : accessoriesCriteria) {
       // define a path to the accessories association that we can use to apply
       // the restrictions
       final Join<Car,String> accessoryJoin = (Join<Car,String>) car.join( "accessories" );
       // or, if using generated metamodel:
       // Join<Car,String> accessoryJoin = car.join( Car_.accessories );

       if (accessoryCriteria.contains("%") {
           criteria.add( cb.like( accessoryJoin, accessoryCriteria ) );
       } 
       else {
           criteria.add( cb.equal( accessoryJoin, accessoryCriteria ) );
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! It works when I only has one element in my accessoriesCriteria, but not two or more. You sure thats it?

Comment: Steve! your code was correct, except that Join<Car,String> accessoryJoin = (Join<Car,String>) car.join( "accessories" ); shall be inside the for loop =) Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, right.  Depends if you want a disjunction (OR) or conjunction (AND) as to where that needs to go.  I changed the code sample to match the conjunction case, which is how `where(Predicate...)` is treated).